# Change files format from '.less' to '.scss'

Tags: bash

I have a folder with a lot of `.less` files.

```
.
..
|__main.less
|__buttons/
     |__buttons.less
     |__button_groups.less
     |__dropdown_button.less
...
```

I have to change their to `.scss`. How I can do it from bash terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below `find` command on the directory where the files you want to rename are stored.

```
find . -type f -name "*.less" -exec rename 's/\.[^.]*$/.scss/' {} \;
```

Comment: Avinash Raj, thanks for answer, but It's doesn't work from my bash. Error message: `find: rename: No such file or directory` :(. I'd like to change file types in projects with architecture like this: https://github.com/pyp/csstree, because sometimes in projects I have to have less, or scss, or stylys.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple - navigate to the folder in cmd - then enter

> ren *.less *.scss